# Keyboard- and Languagesettings not persistent on restart - shutdown start

Tags: macos, startup, sonoma

Whenever I restart my MacBook Pro with M2 Chip and Sonoma 14.1.1 I have to choose the correct keyboard to enter my password.
This does not happen if I lock the screen. It happens since Sonoma. On older macOs (Ventura ...) the keyboard and language settings were persistent upon restart.
There are two different users working on the same MacBook Pro.

However, the ability to change the language on the login screen after restart seems completely gone, choosing the correct keyboard is possible but very annoying.
The default keyboard seems to be us, I am working on a MacBook with a keyboard layout for German Switzerland.

How can I make language and keyboard persistent over restart, for the login screen when the MacBook is rebooted or shutdown and started again.